# Converting excel to pdf using PHP

Tags: php, excel, pdf, laravel-5, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel to create an excel file! I need to save it as .xlsx file and to have a .pdf file

With PHPExcel my pdf appears in a strange format, like this:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUg2b.png)

But I want something like this (this was manually generated, "save as pdf"):
[What I Want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLGNI.png)

Do you know a simple way to convert the excel to pdf?

```
$objReader = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader("Excel2007");
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load(Some_Path);
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);        


$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
        ->setCellValue('B8', "testing");


//Write Excel 
$objWriter = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('testing.xlsx');

// Write PDF
$objWriter = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'PDF');
$objWriter->save('testing.pdf');
```

Comment: can we have some code plz :)

Comment: Yes! I'm sorry @MaximeK :)

Comment: Which PDF Rendering engine are you using? What settings have you enabled for gridlines? `setShowGridlines()` should be set to false for the worksheet

Comment: You probably also need to do some cell merging, or set some column widths

Comment: Are you using PC? If so, PHP can make a COM interface to the Excel object library and use its native [`ExportAsFixedFormat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840291.aspx) method

Comment: I was trying with dompdf

Comment: when I generate the .xlsx file, everything is ok. Including the style of columns, merged cells, etc

Now, I need to open again the excel file that was created and convert him to PDF.

@Parfait , yes I am using PC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a [COM interface](http://php.net/manual/en/book.com.php) to the Excel object library if using PHP for Windows PC. This is a Windows-only extension and usually ships with PHP installation on PCs.

This approach allows you to do practically anything Excel VBA can do including calling the `ExportAsFixedFormat` method to output PDF files. Do note this method can be run on [Workbook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198122.aspx) or [Worksheet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840291.aspx) objects (adhering to preset/default print page settings), even *Chart* and *Range*.

```
// EXCEL APP OBJECT
$xlapp =  new COM("Excel.Application") or Die ("Did not instantiate Excel");

// WORKBOOK AND WORKSHEET OBJECTS
$wbk = $xlapp->Workbooks->Open("C:\\Path\\To\\Workbook.xlsx");    
$wks = $wbk->Worksheets(1);

// SET CELL VALUE
$wks->Range("B8")->Value = "testing";

// OUTPUT WORKSHEET TO PDF
$xlTypePDF = 0;
$xlQualityStandard = 0;

try {
    $wks->ExportAsFixedFormat($xlTypePDF, "C:\\Path\\To\\Output.pdf", $xlQualityStandard);

} catch(com_exception $e) {  
    echo $e->getMessage()."\n";
    exit;

}

// OPEN WORKBOOK TO SCREEN
$xlapp->Visible = true;

// END PROCESS / FREE RESOURCES
$xlapp = NULL;
unset($xlapp);
```

Comment: Can I somehow simulate this COM interface on Linux server?

Comment: Unfortunately, `COM` is a Windows technology. You may have to write a macro in an Excel workbook that does saw thing and have PHP call it via `exec`.

Comment: is there any way to change the pdf setting for exmple i havetwo graphs in excel when i convert to pdf both grahs come in one line and beacuse of space second graph divides into two pages