# How to edit specific excel sheet

Tags: excel, laravel

I have a maser sheet containing multiple sheets. I want to editing DATA sheet shown in the image and I can edit but when i edit the DATA sheet then the data and pivot tables and styling and formatting in Main repot and pivot sheets gets blank . how to stop being formatting and styling gets blank. 
 I am using laravel with maatwebiste.

below is the originalsheet

[image]

but when i store and download the updated sheet the sheet gets blank

[image]

this is data sheet

[image]

```
 Excel::selectSheetsByIndex(2)->load($final_file_path, function($reader) {
    $reader->sheet('Data', function($sheet) {                                     
       $select_arrays = ['85213','Age','40-49','2019-12-01','111111','Not Stated','Not Stated'];
       $sheet->appendRow($select_arrays);

 }, 'UTF-8')->store('xlsx', storage_path('/'), true);
```

Above code is working fine but when store to the path all formatting pivots are removed

Comment: FYI, a "master sheet" is actually called a "Workbook". Workbooks contain sheets. Which is what Main Report, Pivots, and Data are. Also, without code we can't help.

Comment: pls see the code in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Earlier I was using maatwebiste that does not support Pivot but now in my solution I used COM library used for excel.

[Converting excel to pdf using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39333973/converting-excel-to-pdf-using-php)

The solution for the above problem mentioned below:-

```
// WORKBOOK AND WORKSHEET OBJECTS
$wbk = $xlapp->Workbooks->Open("C:\\xampp\htdocs\php-excel1\PivotReportMockUp.xlsx");
$wks = $wbk->Worksheets(2);
$wks1 = $wbk->Worksheets(1);

// SET CELL VALUE
$wks->Range("B2")->Value = "85552";
$wbk->save();

// OUTPUT WORKSHEET TO PDF
$xlTypePDF = 0;
$xlQualityStandard = 0;
$OpenAfterPublish= True; //`enter code here`
$IgnorePrintAreas = True;

try {
   $wks1->ExportAsFixedFormat($xlTypePDF, "C:\\xampp\htdocs\php-excel1\PivotReport.pdf", $xlQualityStandard,$OpenAfterPublish,$IgnorePrintAreas);

} catch(com_exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage()."\n";
    exit;

}
```